# How to mimic timestamp update of file S3 under a certain bucket/folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How to mimic timestamp update of file S3 under a certain bucket/folder (i.e. I would like to do the equivalent of touch filename in UNIX terminology)

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command to achieve the same :

```
aws s3api copy-object --storage-class STANDARD --copy-source <bucket-name>/<file-name> --bucket <bucket-name> --key <file-name>
```

This command will modify the time stamp on the file to be the current time, by telling Amazon to change the storage class to the current storage class. If your storage class is different from STANDARD then use that one in the command.

I have created a file in a bucket and ran the above command, it changed the timestamp of the file to be the current time similar to the touch in Unix.

Comment: This should work, but note there is a filesize limitation of `5368709120`:
`An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120`